How much extra disk space should a postgresql server have?
Suppose you have a PostgreSQL database of total size X hosted on a local server (i.e. expanding disk space in an emergency is difficult). How much space should the server actually be allocated to be safe?
I recently ran into unexpected issues with such a server running out of space unexpectedly due to various background processes, WAL generation, vacuuming, etc. causing temporary ballooning of the amount of space consumed by the database, so you clearly need some headroom.  Given that things like doing a full vacuum of a table can double the space usage of the table, I'm tempted to say that you should just have 2X disk space on the server to be safe, but maybe that's overkill and I'm wondering if there are any rules of thumb for how much disk space should the server should actually be given?

Unfortunately postgres is very bad in managing out of space situations. It might crash. I wish it would instead freeze everything and retry to write repeatedly until the operation was successful. Anyway I posted my experience as a separate answer.

No, there is no rule of thumb.
There are three main factors that determine how much disk space you need:

the amount of data you insert into the database
That is pretty obvious and probably under your control.

temporary files created by queries that need more space than work_mem allows
That's a problem you can easily get under control by setting the temp_file_limit parameter appropriately.

write-ahead log (WAL)
That is usually the biggest problem. The amount of WAL generated depends on your workload: the more data modifications you have (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), the more WAL is written. That amount is quite independent from the size of the database, which is why any rule of thumb that depends on the database size must fail.
Normally, WAL is not a big problem, because PostgreSQL automatically deletes it again after a short while. But there are a few cases in which WAL can grow considerably:

problems with the WAL archiver

stale replication slots (that can be mitigated by setting max_slot_wal_keep_size)

the setting of wal_keep_size is too high (but that's easy to change)




If PostgreSQL runs out of disk space, it will crash, so you want to avoid that. I think that the king's way of dealing with the problem is good monitoring that alerts you in time if disk space is running low. In addition, it is good advice to leave a lot of free disk space. How much depends mostly on your transaction rate, but I wouldn't make it dependent on the size of a database. If a database is very small, I would leave way more free disk space than the size of the database. Conversely, with a 10TB database you don't want to have 10TB of free disk space.
If I were you, I would measure how much WAL the database writes in one day: run
SELECT pg_current_wal_lsn();

on two consecutive days and calculate the difference with
SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff('<second result>', '<first result>');

Then you can make an informed decision. For example, if you leave that much free space, your database can survive a problem with the archiver for one day without crashing.

Very helpful, thanks!

For PostgreSQL, it is of paramount importance to always have empty space. Especially if you keep your tables in the same partition as the WAL (which is the default setup...). If the partition suddenly runs out of space, the database can crash in ugly ways and may leave big files around that are tedious to clean up.
What has bitten me repeatedly is the amount of disk space that maintenance operations like VACUUM FULL need. Imagine the following scenario:

One table is so big that scheduled VACUUM'ing doesn't finish, so it's now even bigger because of accumulating dead tuples (bloat).
You try to manually run a VACUUM FULL to get rid of the bloat, only to see that postgres is growing its size abruptly because it
re-writes the huge table to a new file.
The partition fills up, walwriter gets a disk-space error and postgres crashes ugly, with your primary partition filled up to the brim...

Another factor is the space used in the temp_tablespaces (by default it's the same partition...) by long-running queries on a huge table. It might be as much or more than the huge table itself.
Having been through these scenarios, I'd say that planning for at least as much space available as your database consumes is in general a good practice.
For a very big database I would say have at least 2 x N free space, where N is the size of your biggest table or index. And keep the WAL separate from any tablespaces.
